# Block intent for activity android

Tags: android

`stopService(itnt_BackServices);` are used to stop any background service. but

- how can i stop intent or block it while i press button?

i have lots of serching it but not getting any clue on stop Intent.

**Purpose:** i have use CountdownTimer. as complete countDown it fire finish() method and scope of that i have make startActivity(intent);

now **problem** is, in between countdown i press button and stop my intent. so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest method would be to use a boolean variable in your class:

```
boolean buttonClicked = false;
```

Then, set it to true when button is clicked. If it is true, do not launch the other activity or so.

Comment: i have know about this all fundamental but my entire project is based on timer and each time i have to raise falg and handle exception

Answer (score 0):

You can't really block anything after you have called startActivity. If you have some timer and you need to not call startActivity anymore, just set a flag and check that flag before calling startActivity.

Comment: i have know about this all fundamental but my entire project is based on timer and each time i have to raise falg and handle exception

Comment: i want to stop intent simply ☺